# excel VBA macro to parse multi-line tabbed textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new making macros for excel and I think I'm being a bit too ambitious in my latest project. I basically want to parse the output of a piece of lab equipment to help me file cells in a file that I will use to process my experimental data.

I wanted to paste the raw output from the device in a text box, and then have a macro split the data across multiple cells.
In the raw data, text is separated horizontally by tabs and vertically by line breaks.

E.g.

data1 [tab] data2 [tab] data3 [Line break]
data4 [tab] data5 [tab] data6 [LB]

and so on, which would then be parsed into 3 cells horizontally across 2 cells vertically.

Any ideas how to do this easily?

cheers
Yossi.

Comment: The *easiest* way is probably to start recording a macro then manually use the *Data => From Text* tool to do an import, stop recording and monkey about with the generated code.  (This will not involve the use of a textbox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the value of the textbox twice, first create rows, and then further split that into cells.

```
Dim rows As Variant
Dim columns As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = 1
rows = Split(TextBox1.Value, vbNewLine)

For Each r In rows

j = 1
columns = Split(r, vbTab)

For Each c In columns

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value = c

j = j + 1

Next c
i = i + 1
Next r
```